# Stem and leaf plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I imported a csv dataset with 10 different columns.

One of the columns in **Change**.

I am trying to plot a Stem and Leaf plot using Mathematica.

The example Mathematica code `StemLeafPlot[{1.2, 2.5, 4.1, 1.6, 3.8, 2.6, 2.9}]` works fine.

However when I try to use the **Change** column as a parameter in the StemLeafPlot function it does not work.

```
col10 = DataSet1[[All, {10}]]

StemLeafPlot[col10 ]
```

I get an error `StemLeafPlot::ndata: The argmuent at position 1 is not a list of real numbers.`

Any suggestions how to resolve this error is much appreciated.

Here is the list of dataelements in this column

```
{"NA", -0.7, "NA", 0.88, 
"NA", 0, -0.6, -1.4, "NA", -0.65, "NA", -0.72, "NA", -1.08, -0.7, -1, 
0.1, 0.6, -0.31, "NA", 0.4, -0.7, 1.45, "NA", 0.43, "NA", -0.3, "NA", 
-0.13, "NA", -0.82, "NA", -0.06, "NA", -0.14, -0.17, "NA", 0, 3.07, 
-2.17, 0, -0.2, "NA", -1.75, "NA", -2.4, "NA", -0.96, -0.29, "NA", 
-2.3, "NA", 0.18, -0.07, "NA", -1.52, "NA", 0.47, "NA", -1.5, "NA", 
-0.12, -0.28, "NA", 3.85, "NA", 0.04, "NA", -0.97, "NA", 0.6, "NA", 
-0.84, "NA", -1.2, "NA", 0.06, "NA", 0.6, -1.88, "NA", -0.32, -0.68, 
"NA", 0.34, 1.66, "NA", 0.71, "NA", 0.2, 1.49, "NA", -0.44, "NA", 
0.03, -0.9, "NA", -0.7, -0.28, "NA", 0, 0.56, "NA", 0.34, "NA", 0, 
-0.1, 0.9, "NA", -0.53, "NA", 0.47, "NA", 0.89, "NA", 6, "NA", -1.17, 
"NA", -0.66, "NA", 0.6, 0, -0.6}
```

Answer (score 0):

StemLeafPlot accepts only real-valued numbers, so remove the "NA" strings.

```
StemLeafPlot[DeleteCases[col10, "NA"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have seen better Software documentation/help files compared to Mathematica.